# Как связать 2 разных меню между собой?

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular-routing

Всем привет!
Изучаю angular 2 и столкнулся с проблемкой.

Итак, есть два меню:

Первое меню

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-bar-list">
            <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" routerLink="{{tab.link}}" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="menu-button">{{tab.label}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</div>
```

Второе меню

```
<div class="toolbar-sub">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-bar-list-items">
            <li *ngFor="let state of states" routerLink="{{state.link}}" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="menu-button-items">{{state.label}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Во втором меню пункты могут меняться в зависимости от того, какой пункт выбран в первом меню. Как это сделать красиво? Все что пробовал не получалось. Но попробовал я явно не все.

Answer (score 0):

А что Вы пробовали?

Выбор пункта в первом меню - это событие. И компонент "Главное меню" (а это ведь у Вас отдельный компонент?) может генерировать это событие для своего родителя.

В свою очередь, список пунктов - это входной параметр для подменю. И оно может реагировать на его изменения. Тут есть два варианта: принимать в качестве параметра Observable или использовать механизм отлавливания изменений свойства. Тут на вкус и на цвет. Мне больше нравится Observable.

Остаётся только каким-то образом связать между собой события первого и вход второго компонента. Возможно, через общий родительский компонент? Если таковой имеется - лучше так. Если нет - можно подумать о некоей шине сообщений всего Вашего single-page app.

Comment: Пробовал как раз через события, но видимо очень коряво. Тоже возникло предположение, что надо как-то через Observable, но не имею понятия как это сделать. Еще зеленый совсем я в Angular 2.

Comment: Observable - это скорее RxJS, чем Ангуляр. Это коллекция, элементы которой становятся доступны с течением времени. И на каждый новый элемент можно подписаться. Для того, чтобы записать свои элементы в Observable, удобно использовать  Subject. 
Что касается Ангуляра, то нужно помнить, что компоненты составляют дерево. И родителю доступны события потомка в первом колене. На каждое событие родитель может делать запись в Subject, который отдавать на вход другому своему потомку. Нужно правильно выделить компоненты и сформулировать их бизнес-логику в форме событий и входных свойств.

Comment: Блин, я новичок. Что вроде бы надо сделать так и так я понимаю. Проблема как раз в реализации

Comment: Документация Вам в помощь. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html . По шагам: в компоненте, который должен издавать событие, объявляете new EventEmitter() и аннотируете его [at]Output-ом. Тогда родительский компонент может в тэге прицепить к этому event emitter-у свой обработчик. Предполагаю, что родительский компонент также будет содержать свойство типа Subject http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/behavior_subject/index.html и при отлове требуемого события писать в этот Subject. Вторичное меню должно принимать его на вход и подписываться.

Comment: Попробуйте. Если что-то не получается - задавайте конкретные вопросы по коду. Желательно написать, как именно Вы пытались сделать, чего ожидали и что получилось вместо этого.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не понимаю что я делаю, используя `Subject` и `Observable`, и это проблема. Ваши ссылки не очень помогли. Вот  у меня есть `MenuComponent` и `SubmenuComponent`.

Можно ли сделать так, что когда я нажимаю пункт главного меню, то в сервис отправляется, например, имя этого пункта меню и на основе его сервис возвращает нужно пункты для подменю? Почему лучше использовать `Observable`?

Comment: Вероятно, тут нужно начать с введения в RxJS. Потому что для работы с Ангуляром это нужно. Если у Вас нет проблем с английским - лучше почитать оригинальные тексты, их много. В двух словах, Observable можно рассматривать как поток событий, поступающих с течением времени. И на этот поток можно подписаться. Таким образом, обработчик будет срабатывать при каждом событии. Различными потоками событий можно манипулировать с помощью большого набора операторов из комплекта RxJS. В Вашей ситуации задача - получить поток событий типа "Выбран пункт главного меню".

Comment: Subject - это Observable и Observer в одном флаконе. С одной стороны, на него можно подписаться как на Observable. C другой, у него есть методы для публикации событий. В компоненте, являющемся родителем для главного и вторичного меню можно публиковать в Subject при обработке события, отловленного из главного меню. Родительский компонент может подписаться на событие дочернего с помощью атрибута (childEvent)="eventHandler($event)" при объявлении дочернего компонента в родительском шаблоне.

Comment: Для того, чтобы издать событие, доступное родительскому компоненту, дочерний в своём классе объявляет свойство, помеченное аннотацией Output типа EventEmitter. У EventEmitter-а есть метод, позволяющий опубликовать событие. См. документацию к API Ангуляра. Невдивительно, что EventEmitter имплементирует интерфейс Subject из RxJS.

Comment: Таким образом, получается следующая архитектура: главное меню ничего не знает о существовании второстепенного. Но умеет издавать событие, когда в нём выбирают пункт. Второстепенное меню ничего не знает о главном, но принимает во входном параметре поток событий, которые умеет обрабатывать, меняя свой список пунктов. И, опять же, издаёт событие, когда в нём выбрали пункт. Родительский элемент содержит их обоих, умеет обрабатывать их события и формирует нужный поток событий, чтобы подавать на вход второстепенному меню. Кажется, в наборе стандартных паттернов ООП это называется "Медиатор".

Comment: начал делать так, как Вы написали, но получилось немного не то. Подскажите, я иду в правильном направлении или абы куда?
``

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/yxitSD4ckpJn51mSpbfs/ - правда там какой-то косяк, пока не понял из-за чего. Ну и красоты в коде пока тоже нет)